# Problemas con la propagación de eventos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo problemas con la propagación de eventos en varios de mis elementos. El primer problema es cuando quiero crear un nuevo acordeón-hijo, ya que cuando presiono editar nombre se desliza el acordeón. El segundo problemas es cuando le doy click al botón que tiene icono de cuadricula, cuando le doy click me aparece una tabla y cuando vuelvo a presionar el mismo botón pero con otro icono, me aparece el acordeón-hijo de antes, el problema viene a ser lo mismo al momento de editar la pregunta, ya que se desliza el acordeón, y si creo otros acordeones-hijo pasa lo mismo. ¿A qué se debe esto?

Puse el código en este enlace ya que es un poco largo y SO no me permite poner de más.

https://jsfiddle.net/u4a76qtr/

Answer (score 1):

tu error es que no evitas la propagacion del click a otros elementos.

puedes hacerlo asi:

**primer cambio:**

```
// evitamos la progacion del click
 $(document).on("click", ".rejilla", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
```

**segundo cambio:**

```
// le pasamos el evento
onclick="cambiar_nombre(event,this);";
```

**tercer cambio:**

```
//recibimos el evento y evitamos la propagacion
function cambiar_nombre(event,valor) {

     event.stopPropagation();
```

**cuarto cambio:**

```
function limitar(e, contenido, caracteres) {
 e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Hola amigo  @Bryro, los cambios que me recoemndaste me salieron con error. El mensaje de error era "VM3118 acordeon17.js:408 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stopPropagation is not a function".

Comment: perdon error mio es es el event. ya lo corregi!